# login loop: systemd-udevd[713]: failed to execute '/bin/systemctl start --no-block nvidia-persistenced.service': No such file or directory

Tags: nvidia, login, systemd

My PC was working yesterday without any problem. I shut it down and tried to open this morning. It prints out these messages on the black screen:

```
systemd-udevd[713]: failed to execute '/bin/systemctl' '/bin/systemctl start --no-block nvidia-persistenced.service': No such file or directory

systemd-udevd[852]: failed to execute '/bin/systemctl' '/bin/systemctl stop--no-block nvidia-persistenced': No such file or directory
```

It then continued with the login screen. I entered my password and pressed <kbd>enter</kbd>. It waited for a while and the login screen reappeared again.

How can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 3):

In case someone else has this problem, this is what worked for me:

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to open a terminal and log in.
- Run `sudo apt-get install nvidia-current`, then `sudo reboot`

It downgraded to nvidia-304 and everything was fine after reboot

Comment: I had this message since I upgraded to nvidia-384, but also random freezes after wake-up, which I never had before; hope this will solve this problem too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you've got two problems; the `systemd-udevd` looks like it is a problem with the Nvidia driver. I managed to cure mine by reinstalling an earlier version from 367.57 back to 340.98, it's all in the Software & Updates screen.

That of course is no good at all if you are in a login loop. I've also had that problem in the past a few times and had to got to the terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) and put this code in:

```
sudo mv ~/.Xauthority ~/.Xauthority.backup
```

Then

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

That should at least get you past the login loop so you can change the driver.

Comment: I tried what you suggest but it didn't help. I also went through other suggested solutions and checks. None of them solved my problem. Since I was in hurry, I had to format my PC.

Answer (score 1):

This message appears to be fairly innocuous, not affecting the driver function. You can confirm the driver function by running `inxi -Fxz`: you should see something like:

```
Graphics:  Card: NVIDIA Device 1b81 bus-ID: 01:00.0
           Display Server: X.Org 1.15.1 drivers: nvidia (unloaded: fbdev,vesa,nouveau)
           Resolution: 1920x1080@60.0hz
           GLX Renderer: GeForce GTX 1070/PCIe/SSE2 GLX Version: 4.5.0 NVIDIA 375.82 Direct Rendering: Yes
```

I get the OP's error message running Linux Mint Rosa 17.3, which does not use systemd (it uses Upstart as init). Thus, no surprise that `/bin/systemctl` does not exist. Nvidia should not be trying to call it. More info [in this thread](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=233113).

If you're unable to log in, there's likely something else wrong.

Comment: FYI for those reading: `inxi` is very useful, but it doesn't come standard on Ubuntu 16.04 and must be installed with `sudo apt-get install inxi`