# Ubuntu login loop 14.04 after update and message repeatingly printing to terminal

Tags: command-line, nvidia, login

After an update, I've been having a login loop and I can't log in.  I've tried to search for some solutions and followed a suggestion to reinstall nvidia.

Now I have this message that is constantly printing out to the terminal so I can't even use ctrl+alt+F1-6:

```
systemd-udevd[713]: failed to execute '/bin/systemctl' '/bin/systemctl start --no-block nvidia-persistenced.service': No such file or directory

systemd-udevd[852]: failed to execute '/bin/systemctl' '/bin/systemctl stop--no-block nvidia-persistenced': No such file or directory
```

Could someone please help?

Comment: Hello welcome to Askubuntu.  Could you be more specific in your question and give some details on how you reinstalled nvidia, as well as the version of nvidia.

Comment: Going on Ubuntu Software Centre history, I had nvidia 367 (367.57-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) before the last reinstall, and in the morning when the problem started, nvidia 304 (340.101-0ubuntu0.14.04.1).  When reinstalliing using 'sudo apt-get install nvidia-current', which seems to have fixed the issue, it installed nvidia 304 (340.134-0ubuntu0.14.04.1).

Answer (score 0):

So, I found an old Ubuntu Rescue Remix DVD and booted from it.  Then I rebooted and this time booted from the hard disk to get back to the login screen.  On pressing `ctrl+alt+F1`, I was delighted to see the normal login prompt again and not that message constantly printing out in the terminal. Afterwards, I decided to follow Cuzschek's suggestion in this post:

[login loop: systemd-udevd[713]: failed to execute '/bin/systemctl start --no-block nvidia-persistenced.service': No such file or directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/846956/login-loop-systemd-udevd713-failed-to-execute-bin-systemctl-start-no-blo)

I ran `sudo apt-get install nvidia-current`, then `sudo reboot` and was able to log back into Ubuntu.

Comment: If your answer is essentially a referral to another question, it would be better to [flag](/help/privileges/flag-posts) this question as a duplicate of the other once you [earned 15 reputation](/help/whats-reputation). Don't forget to vote for the answer(s) there that you found useful!